# Question About Intermediate Step in finding a limit

Tags: real-analysis

So I have a question in finding the limit of this sequence:

Let $$a_n :=(4^{10}+n2^n)^\frac{1}{n}$$

My attempt:

Take out a factor of n and use the result $(n)^\frac{1}{n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$

So we get $$a_n :=(\frac{2^{20}}{n}+2^n)^\frac{1}{n}$$

Now here is my question, can I use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{20}}{n} = 0$

And substitute that into the brack to arrive to the answer of 2?$[(2^n)^\frac{1}{n} = 2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not allowed to take the limit under a power of $n$.

Here is an approach: For $n \geq 20$

$a_n =(4^{10}+n2^n)^\frac{1}{n}=(2^{20}+n2^n)^\frac{1}{n} \leq (20.2^{20}+n2^n)^\frac{1}{n} \leq (n.2^{n}+n2^n)^\frac{1}{n} \leq (n.2^{n+1})^\frac{1}{n}$

and: $(n2^n)^\frac{1}{n} \leq a_n =(4^{10}+n2^n)^\frac{1}{n} $

Now use Squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t treat the limits separately.

For a very simple and well-known example demonstrating this, take

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$

If you treat $\frac{x}{n}$ separately and take the limit as $n \to \infty$, you will get $(1+0)^n = 1^n = 1$, which is incorrect, as the limit equals $e^x$.